# Error linking standard header file in gcc

Tags: gcc, c

I've a simple code - this works on other platforms but does not work in ubuntu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int x=99;
char str[100];
itoa(99, str, 10);
return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile in using terminal in gcc with :

```
gcc test.c
```

But I get the error:

```
/tmp/ccJN77g6.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `itoa'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why so? prototype for itoa is included in stdlib.h

Comment: This question turns out to be about how the C library on Ubuntu doesn't contain the `itoa` function, which is contained by C library implementations on some other operating systems. So should this really be considered off-topic for our site? Is the community at Stack Overflow really better suited to this question? In any case, if the answer is yes, I suggest this be migrated.

Comment: @EliahKagan - add this as an answer and lets get a couple of upvotes for you to close.

Comment: It's been in stackoverflow awhile:                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462938/error-itoa-was-not-declared-in-this-scope

Answer (score 3):

`itoa` doesn't seem to be ANSI C++ and thus is very likely to be not supported by gcc.

According to [this source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/), a the following workaround is suggested:

```
This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers.

A standard-compliant alternative for some cases may be sprintf:

    sprintf(str,"%d",value) converts to decimal base.
    sprintf(str,"%x",value) converts to hexadecimal base.
    sprintf(str,"%o",value) converts to octal base.
```

A `sprintf` reference can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/).

Answer (score 1):

`itoa` function is not portable, non standard and most Linux compilers doesn't support it.

Instead you should use `snprintf()` function

Check the **snprintf** reference [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int x=99;
char str[100];
// itoa(99, str, 10);
snprintf(str,10,"%d", x);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the code you entered and I get the same error. It would appear that itoa() isn't ANSI C standard and doesn't work with GCC on Linux (at least the version I'm using). Things like this are frustrating especially if you want your code to work on different platforms (Windows/Linux/Solaris/whatever).

It is not a standard C function. Here are some links that might get you started to find a way around the function:

[link1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/)
[Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux)

Hope it helps.